# How to instantiate a class with another class' instance as attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, instantiation

I am trying to learn Python on my own.
I have this code snippet:

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.tank = Tank()


class Tank():

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tank_size = kwargs.get('tank_size', None)

    def describe_tank(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.tank_size) + "-L tank.")
```

Is it possible to instantiate Car without specifying a default value for parameter `tank_size` in the `__init__` of Tank class? 
Thank you.
P.S. Edited code a bit to make it more logical.

Comment: No, probably not. Why do you need to do this? As an aside, `.describe_battery()` should return a string, not print the result.

Comment: Not as written, in any sane way. Why don't you just provide a default argument, or make your constructor not take a tank_size? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I learn Python from a book, there was an example of class instance as attribute in another class, default value was set, but I was just curious if instantiation is possible without default value in this particular setup. I am not trying to solve an actual problem and I do know I could return a value instead of printing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try access it with kwargs.get and provide default value there.

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tank_size = kwargs.get('tank_size', None)
```

So now you can pass tank_size to Car constructor and further to the Tank's one. If you still don't want to use default value you can pass it through kwargs again.

```
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, **kwargs):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

        self.tank = Tank(**kwargs)
```

So it would be like

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, **kwargs):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

        self.tank = Tank(**kwargs)

class Tank():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tank_size = kwargs.get('tank_size', None)

    def describe_tank(self):
        if self.tank_size:
            print("This car has a " + str(self.tank_size) + "-L tank.")
        else:
            print("No info about the tank.")



car = Car("bmw", "m5", 2000)
car.tank.describe_tank()

new_car = Car("bmw", "m5", 2000, tank_size=3)
new_car.tank.describe_tank()
```

Comment: Spasibo, Timur. I can instantiate with 0 tank, like c=Car("bmw", "m5", 2000), then I have None-L tank. But what if I want to set tank size on instantiation, how do I do that? I tried variants but nothing works.

Comment: I have edited my answer but still think that default value for tank_size looks much more cleaner. @NoPasaran

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, but this solution will limit you in extend the input of Tank class, you have to manually handle all additional attributes in the future.

```
class Tank():
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        if args:           
            self.tank_size = args[0]
        else:
            self.tank_size = "Not Specified"

    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a {}-L tank.".format(self.tank_size))
```

As well for string formatting i would recommend the .format builtin function.

Comment: Köszönöm. I can instantiate without tank, like c=Car("bmw", "m5", 2000), but how do I instantiate Car while setting tank_size to, say, 70?

Comment: That has to be handled in the Car class,  so the keyword argument is lifted from Tank to Car, like class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year,Tank_Size=None):
        if Tank_Size:
   self.tank = Tank(Tank_Size)
  else:
   self.tank = Tank()

Answer (score 0):

You can always keep it as an attribute and remove it from the initialization params.

```py
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.tank = Tank()


class Tank():

    def __init__(self):
        self.tank_size = None

    def set_tank_size(self, size):
        self.tank_size = size

    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.tank_size) + "-L tank.")
```

Or if you want to do it properly, you can use a property and a setter.

```py
from number import Real


class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.tank = Tank()


class Tank():

    def __init__(self):
        self._tank_size = None

    @property
    def tank_size(self):
        return self._tank_size

    @tank_size.setter
    def tank_size(self, size):
        if not isinstance(size, Real):
            raise TypeError('Tank `size` must be a number.')
        if not size >= 0:
            raise ValueError('Tank `size` must be >= 0.') # electrics have a 0-L tank?
        self._tank_size = size

    def describe_battery(self):
        print("This car has a " + str(self.tank_size) + "-L tank.")
```

Comment: Thank you, James. The first snippet I understand, instantiate Car with just make, model and year and then set tank size with instance.tank.set_tank_size(). The second is "above my pay grade" for now as I am just a beginner who tries to understand basic inheritance concept.